# How can I select with hibernate.query from an intermediate table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have three tables `Job`, `JobSeeker` and `Job_applications` which is the intermediate table. The relation between `Job` and `JobSeeker` is n to n. How can I write a hibernate query or criteria to select a List(Job) with `Job.id` and `Job.applicantsCount` which counts how many `JobSeeker` applied to that Job.

`Job` entity:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="JOB_APPLICATIONS",  
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_job", referencedColumnName="id")},  
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_job_seeker", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private List<JobSeeker> jobSeekers = new ArrayList<JobSeeker>();

    @Transient
    @Expose


    private Integer applicantsCount = 0;

    ...
```

`JobSeeker` entity:

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="JOB_APPLICATIONS",  
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_job_seeker", referencedColumnName="id")},  
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_job", referencedColumnName="id")})
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
    ....
```

In normal SQL, I write something like this: `select id,(select count(*) from job_applications where id_job = id ) as applicantsCount from job`

This works but I need it with hibernate.Query or hibernate.Criteria in a List(Job). Can somebody help me to write this query with hibernate?

**SOLUTION:**
manish comment resolved my problem read it

Comment: If you are open to using Hibernate-specific code, you could do this directly in your entity class. First remove `@Transient` from the `applicantsCount` field. Then, put `@Basic @Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job_applications WHERE id_job=id)")` to get the field value.  Note the `()` enclosing the query which should prevent the Hibernate-generated query from getting garbled.  Then, `job.getApplicantsCount()` should give you the number of applicants for the job.  You could lazy-load this count through the attributes of the `@Basic` annotation.

Comment: Oao nice answer and it works fine. I did not know this @Formula annotation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clear. You should write your entities to give  you better abstraction. Why can't you have a `List<JobApplications>` within the `Job` class so you can get a list:

```
Criteria crit = s.createCriteria(Job.class);
List<Job> jobs =crit.getList();
for(Job j:jobs){
    //j.getId returns the Id of the Job.....and... 
    //j.getJobApplications.size() returns count for that particular job
}
```

Comment: I had like this, but it is ugly for every job to make a query, and I want a single query instead.